# Blinking animation issue

Tags: ios, uiview, uianimation

I'm having an issue with an animation within my view controller.  I have two `UIViews`: Blue view and green view.  Blue view is on top of green view.  Inside of green view I have a `UIView` that is an animating sine wave and a another `UIView` called "recordingIndicatorView" that consists of a text label that has a blinking animation implemented.  When I swipe the Blue view up, green view is revealed and the sine wave view starts animating and recordingIndicatorView starts blinking.  When I swipe Blue view down, the animations end and the sine view and recordingIndicatorView are hidden.

However, if I swipe blue view up, swipe down, and then swipe blue view up quickly, the blinking animation gets thrown off and begins blinking much more rapidly.

```
- (IBAction)handleUpSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    if(viewIsUp == NO)
    {        

         [self.sineWave animateWave];

         [self showSine];

         [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

             [self moveViewsUp];

         } completion:^(BOOL finished){

         }];

         stopBlinking = NO;

        [self.recordingIndicatorView setHidden:NO];
        [self flashOn:self.recordingIndicatorView];

     }
 }

- (IBAction)handleDownSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    if(viewIsUp == YES)
    {

         [self stopRecording];

         if(self.panedView.frame.origin.y <0)
         {

             [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

                [self hideSine];
                [self moveViewsDown];

         } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        [self.sineWave.layer removeAllAnimations];

        }];

        }
    }
}

-(void) stopRecording
{
     stopBlinking = YES;
     [self hideSine];
     [self.recordingIndicatorView setHidden:YES];
}


- (void)flashOff:(UIView *)v
{
     [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^ {
        self.recordingIndicatorView.alpha = 0.01;  
         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        if(stopBlinking == NO)
        {
             [self flashOn:self.recordingIndicatorView];
        }

    }];
}


- (void)flashOn:(UIView *)v
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^ {
         self.recordingIndicatorView.alpha = 1;
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         [self flashOff:self.recordingIndicatorView];
    }];
}

-(void) moveViewsDown
{
    if(viewIsUp)
    {
    self.panedView.frame = CGRectOffset( self.panedView.frame, 0, 274);
    self.sineWave.frame = CGRectOffset(self.sineWave.frame, 0, 246);
    self.micImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.micImageView.frame, 0, 85.5);
    viewIsUp = NO;

    }
}

 -(void) moveViewsUp
{
    if(!viewIsUp)
    {
    self.panedView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.panedView.frame, 0, -274);
    self.sineWave.frame = CGRectOffset(self.sineWave.frame, 0, -246);
    self.micImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.micImageView.frame, 0, -85.5);
    viewIsUp = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your blinking animation is added more than one time. May be some mess with viewIsUp flag. This is all I can find without other code. And try not to use self in blocks it's bad habit and leads to hidden errors and memory leaks, use weak self instead, like:

```
__weak typeof(self) wSelf = self;
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    [wSelf hideSine];
    [wSelf moveViewsDown];
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [wSelf.sineWave.layer removeAllAnimations];
}];
```

Comment: I never heard of the issue with using self and blocks.  Thanks for the heads up.  When you say the animation is added more than once, do you think 'flashOn' is getting called more than once when I swipe up?

Comment: Yes, and I think it is possible if viewIsUp flag is not updated properly.